# How can I prevent my scrolling message within 20 pixels at the end of my list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've this scrolling function here. I want to know if it's possible to prevent the scroll up message within the last 20 pixels at the end? So that when I scroll up from the end the message appears only above the 20 pixels area at the end.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let lastScrollTop = 0;

  $("#wrapper").scroll(function() {
    let st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (st < lastScrollTop) {
      console.log("Scroll up");
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#test {
  background: green;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Grab the inner or outer height of the page, subtract your scroll top, and check against 20

Comment: ^^^ that should say of the wrapper, not the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only want to see the `console.log()` ABOVE the LAST 20 pixels? If so,

---

You can 'calculate' the scrolled pixels by checking the position of the element compared to the maximum scroll height, and comparing that!

<sub>I've increased the 20px size and added an 'else' `console.log()` so the behaviour is easier to spot ;)</sub>

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    let lastScrollTop = 0;

    $("#wrapper").scroll(function() {
        let st = $(this).scrollTop();

        var remainingPixels = $(this).prop('scrollHeight') - ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height());

        if (st < lastScrollTop) {
            if (remainingPixels > 100) {
                console.log("Scroll up", remainingPixels);
            } else {
                console.log('Muted', remainingPixels);
            }
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
    });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#test {
  background: green;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thats what I was looking for! I safely used outerHeight because of some padding.

Answer (score -1):

**Update**
Detect to End less than 20 pixel

Try codes below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let lastScrollTop = 0;

  $("#wrapper").scroll(function() {
    let st = $(this).scrollTop();
    let height = $(this)[0].scrollHeight-$(this).height()
    
    if (st < lastScrollTop && st > height-20)   //Just add another condition st > height-20
    {
      console.log("scroll up, gap to end is : ", height-st);
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#test {
  background: green;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: the question says the end, not the beginning

Comment: The scroll gap between the end and 20 px seems to be very large?